# Rectangular mask in an array

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I would like to apply a mask all around the edges of an array, as example in a 3x3 array :

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

In stack i found this command, but i can t apply a second condition to get my specific array...

```
import numpy as np
np.logical_and.outer(np.arange(3) >= 2, np.arange(3) >= 2)
```

I get that :

```
0 0 0
0 0 0 
0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always construct a mask to deselect the first and last rows/columns like this:

```
>>> mask = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=bool)
>>> mask 
array([[True, True, True],
       [True, True, True],
       [True, True, True]], dtype=bool)

>>> mask[0], mask[-1], mask[:,0], mask[:,-1] = False, False, False, False
>>> mask
array([[ False,  False,  False],
       [ False,  True,   False],
       [ False,  False,  False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the 2-d mask directly from a 1-d mask:

```
In [6]: np.logical_and.outer([0,1,0],[0,1,0])
Out[6]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

EDIT:
For the generic case you can do something like:

```
In [11]: np.logical_and.outer([0]+[1]*3+[0],[0]+[1]*5+[0]).astype(int)
Out[11]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks! ;) But my array is 2092x1936 ^^ and i would like to suppress 100 values at each edge part so i cant do manually..